# How to use eloquent to retrieve a column from another table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables

```
product: id|category ...
category: id|name ...
```

product.category is a foreign key linked to category.id . I am building a basic CRUD and I would like to display all Products in the the product table as well as the name of the category they belong to rather than their category ID. TO do this, while searching the laravel documentation I came across the query builder and I achieved my goal.

```
public function index()
{
    $products = \DB::table('products')
        ->join('categories', 'products.category', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->select('*')
        ->get();

    return view('product' ,compact('products'));
}
```

Under my models for product and category I have created the appropriate relationships.

**product.php** :

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

**category.php** :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

I keep hearing about the power of Eloquent and was wondering how I could achieve a similar result with eloquent and if eloquent is designed for such operations or if the query builder is the right way to go. 
Every tutorial online seems to only use the post and comments scenario of getting all comments belonging to a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::with('category')->get();

    return view('product' ,compact('products'));
}
```

In blade

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{$product->name}}
    {{$product->category->name ?? ''}}
    //or
    @if ($product->category)
        $product->category->name
    @endif

@endforeach
```

Also if in project table foreign key is not equal `category_id`. In your case

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category');
}
```

Comment: what does ?? '' stand for ?

Comment: @uhexos its called [`Null Coalescing Operator`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm). Gets you the first valid value from the arguments

Comment: After making the modifications I got  ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object when I removed the null coalescing operator and when I add it nothing is printed.

Comment: try this is_object($product->category)?$product->category->name:''; will work

Comment: `$product->category->name ?? ''` this syntax used if project has category that case print category name else print empty string

Comment: @Davit after I did a dump of the $products I found out that the $product->category->name needed to be $product->Category->name (capital C). I don't know if this is unique to my case or if there is a mistake in your answer. Thank you for your help .

Comment: `$product->category` property based in your defined relationship `public function category()`